# Android: notifyDataSetChanged() only works on second call

Tags: android, listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Ok so I'm at my wit's end with this.

I've encapsulated the list data update functionality inside a function called 'refreshData' inside the adapter. I then call this function on the adapter inside of onActivityResult (the activity that was started for result sets a completion flag onStop. This completion flag is supposed to determine which styles (colors and text) are applied to a particular list item in the list view. Essentially, user selects "1" and goes to new activity, closes that activity, and "1" get's set to done onStop. Returning to the list activity, the listview should make available "2" while setting "1" to complete (visual cues).

The problem I'm having is, that the update only happens the SECOND time the user clicks the list item to go to the new activity and close to return. Without fail, the listview will update the SECOND time only. I have no clue why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

public class SceneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<SceneItem> data;
Typeface font;
UserDatabaseHelper uDatabase;
int chapter_number;

public SceneAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, int chapter, String FONT) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.chapter_number = chapter;
    this.data = getData(chapter);
    this.font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    int typeCount = 2;
    return typeCount;
}

private ArrayList<SceneItem> getData(int chapter) {
    // bucket to return data
    ArrayList<SceneItem> container = new ArrayList<SceneItem>();

    // titles (need to replace with master database call eventually)
    String[] scenesListJapanese = getSceneTitlesInJapanese(chapter);
    String[] scenesListEnglish = getSceneTitlesInEnglish(chapter);

    // ready database for data retrieval
    initializeUserDatabaseForUse();

    // query for data
    Cursor query = uDatabase.getAllScenesForChapter(chapter + 1);

    // testing line, take out when done
    Log.v("query length: ", ""+ query.getCount());

    // fill data
    for (int i = 0; i < scenesListJapanese.length; i++) {
        SceneItem item = new SceneItem(""+(i+1), scenesListEnglish[i], scenesListJapanese[i],
                query.getInt(4), query.getInt(3));
        container.add(item);
        Log.v("status for chapter " + (chapter + 1) + ": ", "available: " + query.getInt(4)
                + ", completed: " + query.getInt(3));
        query.moveToNext();
    }

    // close db connection
    query.close();

    return container;
}



public void refreshData() {
    data.clear();
    this.data = getData(chapter_number);
    Log.v("refresh data called: ", "NOW!");
}


public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(data.get(position).available == 1 || position == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    SceneHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new SceneHolder();
        holder.chapterNumber = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.scene_number);
        holder.englishTitleBox = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.scene_title_english);
        holder.japaneseTitleBox = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.scene_title_japanese);
        holder.englishTitleBox.setTypeface(font);
        holder.japaneseTitleBox.setTypeface(font);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (SceneHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    if(isEnabled(position)) {
        holder.englishTitleBox.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.gray_subtext));
        holder.chapterNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.number_gray);
        holder.japaneseTitleBox.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.gray_text));
        holder.chapterNumber.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.white_text));
        row.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.transparent));
    } else {
        holder.englishTitleBox.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.standard_gray));
        holder.chapterNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.number_transparent);
        holder.japaneseTitleBox.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.standard_gray));
        holder.chapterNumber.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.standard_gray));
        row.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.action_gray_end));
    }

    SceneItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.chapterNumber.setText(item.scene);
    holder.englishTitleBox.setText(item.titleEnglish);
    holder.japaneseTitleBox.setText(item.titleJapanese);
    return row;
}

static class SceneHolder
{
    TextView englishTitleBox;
    TextView japaneseTitleBox;
    TextView chapterNumber;
}

// Get english scene titles based on chapter number
private String[] getSceneTitlesInEnglish(int position) {
    // generate and return list
}

// Get japanese scene titles based on chapter number
private String[] getSceneTitlesInJapanese(int position) {
    // generate and return list
}

public void initializeUserDatabaseForUse() {
    // init database
}
```

}

Code for calling activity:

public class SceneSelectActivity extends Activity {

```
ListView mListView; // list view to display scene data
int chapterNumber; // chapter number to use for displaying scenes
Intent passedIntent; // passed intent containing data on which chapter was selected
UserDatabaseHelper uDatabase; // user database reference
SceneAdapter sceneAdapter; // adapter reference
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1; // request code for activity result

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scene_select);

    // Setup necessary variables and views for this activity
    initializeUserDatabaseForUse();
    handleSetup();

    Button backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scene_back_button);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);

    sceneAdapter.refreshData();
    sceneAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

// Handle set up of activity views and variables
private void handleSetup() {

    // passed intent holding data on which chapter was selected
    passedIntent = getIntent();

    // chapter number to be used in deciding what data/views to set up
    chapterNumber = getChapterNumber(passedIntent);

    // setup list data, and views
    setDataForThisScene(chapterNumber);
    setMainImage(chapterNumber);
}

// Obtain chapter number from passed intent
private int getChapterNumber(Intent i) {
    // ensure the data is a valid number for a chapter
    return i.getIntExtra("chapter_number", 0);

}

// Set up data to be used for list view
private void setDataForThisScene(int position) {
    // set chapter splash content
    Resources res = getResources();
    TextView splashJ = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scene_splash_title_j);
    TextView splashE = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scene_splash_title_e);
    final String title_english[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.chapters_english);
    final String title_japanese[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.chapters_japanese);
    splashJ.setText(title_japanese[chapterNumber]);
    splashE.setText(title_english[chapterNumber]);
    TextView completionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scene_progress);
    completionView.setText(getCompletionStatus(chapterNumber + 1));

    // setup scene list
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scene_list);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(SceneSelectActivity.this, DialogueActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("chapter_number", chapterNumber);
            i.putExtra("scene_number", position);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            //startActivity(i);
            // LIST ON CLICK ITEM EVENTS
        }
    });
    //SceneAdapter sceneAdapter = new SceneAdapter(this, R.layout.scene_list_item, sceneData, "custom_font_regular.otf");
    sceneAdapter = new SceneAdapter(this, R.layout.scene_list_item, chapterNumber, "custom_font_regular.otf");
    mListView.setAdapter(sceneAdapter);
}

private String getCompletionStatus(int chapter) {
    Cursor query = uDatabase.getAllScenesForChapter(chapter);
    int completed = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < query.getCount(); i++) {
        if(query.getInt(3) != 0) {
            completed += 1;
        }
        query.moveToNext();
    }
    query.close();
    return completed * 100 / query.getCount() + "%";
}

// fill in image for chapter bg
private void setMainImage(int chapterNumber) {
    // generate image
}

// initialize database
public void initializeUserDatabaseForUse() {
    // init database
}
```

}

The LOG.v inside the 'refreshData' function DOES get called each time the detail activity is closed and the user returns to this list view activity. Although it gets called every time, the list only updates the SECOND time the user repeats the action.

Comment: I had a similar issue where `notifyDataSetChanged()` did not work on the first call, but worked on all subsequent calls. However, my data structure is completely different from yours. The problem I faced resulted from the database query showing up as `null` the first time but working on all subsequent tries. I worked around it by simply checking if the database query returned `null` the first time, and if it did, just make a new query. Perhaps something similar is happening with your database calls?